# CGI Python os.system

Tags: python, apache, cgi

I am just wondering if it is possible to run a system call from a CGI script on Apache.  Here's part of the code:

```
print "<input type = 'submit' value = 'Launch Job!'>"
print "</form>"
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
system('command')
```

I am trying to run this command on the same computer that is hosting the web page.  Problem is that when this function executes, the command does not run successfully.  I have tried adding `sudo` to the beginning, tried `os.system('command')` all to no avail.

So, is this possible?

Comment: It might be helpful to explain what you're trying to do. Perhaps you don't need to use an external utility?

Answer (score 0):

Commands will be run as the user `nobody`, and have very few privileges.

Comment: Thanks Louis, is there a way to change that?

Comment: You can set the setuid bit of the executable, this means it will run with the permissions of the owner of the file. **WARNING** If the owner is root, this may pose a *serious* security risk. You could create a wrapper script owned by the apache user for example.

Comment: You could make a server running as a normal user taking requests to do certain operations over dbus or sockets. The cgi script could then request the job be started.

Answer (score 0):

try **subprocess**:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
a = subprocess.check_output(["date"]) # this is your command
#print os_date
print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print '<html>'
print '<head>'
print '<title>Hello Word!</title>'
print '</head>'
print '<body>'
print '<h2>Hello Word! Today is: %s</h2>' % a
print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

if the server gives 500 error, try **cgi**:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

try:
    import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
except:
    pass
import sys, cgi, os
sys.stderr = sys.stdout
from time import strftime
import traceback
from StringIO import StringIO
from traceback import print_exc


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Content-type: text/html"         
    print                                   
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    thecmd = "python yourscript.py" # this is your command
    if thecmd:
        print '<HR><BR><BR>'
        print '<B>Command : ', thecmd, '<BR><BR>'
        print 'Result : <BR><BR>'
        try:
            child_stdin, child_stdout = os.popen2(thecmd)
            child_stdin.close()
            result = child_stdout.read()
            child_stdout.close()
            print result.replace('\n', '<BR>')

        except Exception, e:                
            print errormess
            f = StringIO()
            print_exc(file=f)
            a = f.getvalue().splitlines()
            for line in a:
                print line
```